# Is there a way to add an attribute table to a qgis2web export?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, table, qgis2web

I use `qgis2web` for mapping building type in some area then publish it on web, so it needs a list (or table) to show on web that only a few building (not all building in that area) that I used.

Is there any way to show table (or list) of building that I used through `qgis2web` leaflet?

**edited**: I'm using qgis 2.8.3 (Wien) and qgis2web 1.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that qgis2web does not support this. However, your data is exported in GeoJSON format, so if you can find a Javascript plugin to read that data and present it as an HTML table, that will do the job for you. There may be Leaflet and/or OpenLayers 3 plugins to do this as well, but it's not something I've looked into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom! I only want to know if qgis2web supported to make a table, maybe I'll try other way to do that :)